# various ways to find elements by using Webdriver @FindBy annotations

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am trying to find the solution for my Webdriver script to work. I need your help to find the solution in my scenario.

I have a web application that creates form by using tabbed screen. There is a Next and Back buttons that have similar attributes and I cant find the solution.

xpath doesn't work, CSS has the same name and its getting confused.

here is the "Next" button that needs to be clicked:

```js
<div class="button" style="margin-right: 5px;">
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:submitForm('metaStudyAction!moveToData.action')" value="Next">
```

I would like to use @FindBy annotation to find the element. Can I use HOW with multiple attributes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css` for multiple attributes

```
@FindBy(css = "[type='button'][value='Next']")
private WebElement button;
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks so much

Comment: Accept the answer please.